# Why am I getting access denied error even though users belong to local admin group?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Environment SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 on a development environment.

After installation of the Database, SSRS, SSAS (OLAP) and Tabular (Separate instance), and SSIS everything was fine and accessable.

Several weeks later, a power user (with local admin privs) reported that he received the 'Access is Denied' message when attempting to log into SSIS.  This happened at very nearly the same time as when a log mount point filled up.  I immediately shrunk the log and resolved the issue behind the log filling but I then also received the same message when attempting to log on to SSIS.

The common end-point to resolve this issue is the URL [**Connect to a Remote Integration Services Server (SSIS Service)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337083.aspx), which is to add any non-local admin to the DCOM User group.  But since this user and I are both members of the local administrator group this is not a resolution.  And another power user with local admin privs worked just fine prior to the issue but not after.

I performed the standard restart to no avail followed by an uninstall/reinstall of SSIS, again to no avail.  My next option would be to reinstall SQL Server.  Although this would be a possibility it would not alleviate having to do it all over again if the problem recurs.

Has anyone run into this or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Regardless of local admin or not, I would still add the DcOM permissions and see what happens. I have seen similar things, again with admin rights, and DcOM is almost always the answer.

Comment: I have looked in DCOM and it is set the same as the other servers that work correctly.  The local admins are given local launch and access.  If I would want to give others that are not local admins the ability to use SSIS I would need to add them to DCOM but since they are local admins I do not need to explicitly add them.

Comment: You are correct and set me on the right track, it is a DCOM permissions thing.  Thanks.  When I explicitly added myself it worked just fine.  So I deleted the local admin group from DCOM, restarted the SSIS task, readded the local admin group and restarted the SSIS group but it was no good.  For some reason the local admin group is just hosed in the DCOM permissions.  For now I have explicitly added everyone from the local admin group.  Do you know the registry keys that are involved for these DCOM entries?  Perhaps I will need to go that route to fix it.

Comment: Let me say, the suggestion of adding users to the DCOM group solved my problem of "access denied even when local admin or domain admin". For whatever reason the DCOM group on my server was completely empty. Adding in the needed accounts fixed everything. Amen.

Answer (score 0):

This will almost certainly be a **DCOM** issue. If you want to resolve these issues through the registry, then the keys are as follows: Sorry, I don't know the GUIDs.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{GUID}\AccessPermission
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{GUID}\AuthenticationLevel
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{GUID}\LaunchPermission
```